# Animation for power rule (differentiation)

Tags: beamer, animations, animate

Context:  Let's say I'm teaching an online Calc I course.

So, I set up some slides in beamer to illustrate the power rule, but it would be nice to have a little animation where the old power drops down and becomes a coefficient:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^4\right]=4x^3$$

Is there some software that could animate this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not a free coding service.  For software recommendations ask over at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay.  Just FYI, it's not as if I don't try to do things myself first.  I make sure I exhaust my own ideas before I bother others.

Comment: Well, you haven't shown anything you tried in the question, so I assume that this is just a lame excuse.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Henri Menke but just for fun:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[3][]{\tikz[remember
picture,baseline=(#2.base)]{\node(#2)[inner sep=0pt,#1]{#3};}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcount\myangle

\begin{document}
\transduration{2}
\animate<2-21>
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame title}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{8cm}
\animatevalue<2-21>{\myangle}{0}{19}
\[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[x^{\tikznode[opacity={\myangle/19}]{start}{$\scriptstyle 4$}}\right]
=\tikznode{end}{\phantom{4}}
\visible<2->{\tikznode[opacity={\myangle/19}]{xcubed}{$x^3$}}\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Frac}{\myangle/19}
\path (start.center) to[out=0,in=135] node[pos=\Frac,scale={2/3+\Frac/3},
rotate={-\Frac*360}]{$4$} (end.center) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\visible<2->{` instead of only would prevent the jump on the first slide

Comment: @samcarter Thanks! (It turns out to be much more effort than I thought. Originally I thought it would be less effort to write an answer than a polite comment along the lines of Henri, but you are right, when posting an answer one should do a proper job. ;-)